# Check if setter is invoked?

Tags: java

I have function written where I traverse a HTTP query string parameters and set a two POJO classes attributes by reading the string. Some query string parameters belong to first class and some to another class.

Eg: `http://example.com?crb=nmsa&cra=jasdlka&....` 
 I am reading crb, cra, etc from a `Map`

```
Pojo pojo = new Pojo();


for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> queryParameter : queryParamsAndValues.entrySet()) {

    System.out.println(queryParameter.getKey() + "/" + queryParameter.getValue());

    queryFieldName = QueryFieldName.getLongName(queryParameter
            .getKey());



    switch (queryFieldName) {

    case CREATED_BEFORE:
        pojo.setCreatedBefore(queryParameter.getValue()
                .get(0));
        System.out.println("CREATED BEFORE");
        break;
    case CREATED_AFTER:
        pojo
        .setCreatedAfter(queryParameter.getValue().get(0));
        System.out.println("CREATED AFTER");
        break;
    case FILTER_USAGE:
        pojo.setFilterUsage(new BigInteger(queryParameter
                .getValue().get(0)));
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    case RESULT_CONTENT:
        pojo2.setResultContent(new BigInteger(queryParameter
                .getValue().get(0)));
        System.out.println("Result Content: " + new BigInteger(queryParameter.getValue().get(0)));
        break;
    case RESPONSE_TYPE:

        ResponseTypeInfo resTypeInfo = new ResponseTypeInfo();
        resTypeInfo.setResponseTypeValue(new BigInteger(queryParameter.getValue().get(0)));
        pojo2.setResponseType(resTypeInfo);
    default:
        System.out.println("DEFUALT");
    }
}

reqPrim.setPojo(pojo);

}else{
    reqPrim.setPojo(null);
}
```

So `pojo` and `pojo2` are being set after reading query string.

Now I want to know if any attribute of `pojo` is set or not.
One option is setting a flag to true every time an attribute of `pojo` is set.

Is there any efficient way ??

Comment: You could check if the fields of your pojos are ``null`` after the loop.

Comment: That would mean checking each field separtely, which would be cumbersome

Comment: Set a flag in the select..case statement -- or, rather, an enum with values like 'pojo', 'pojo2', 'both', 'neither'. Or, use aspects (overkill).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your pojo to use a map as container for all your properties. Then "any property set" translates to call "isEmpty()" on that map. Or you directly use the built-in java [properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

you can hold a two maps`MAP<String,Object>` the key is going to be the name of the pojo field and the value is what ever you passed to that field , this way you know what you have set and what you havent

```
Map<String,Object> pojoMap= new HashMap<>();
Map<String,Object> pojo2Map= new HashMap<>();
//when ever i set the field i put it in the map
pojo.setCreatedBefore(queryParameter.getValue().get(0));
pojoMap.put("createdBefore",queryParameter.getValue().get(0));
//you can check the field that are set
boolean isCreatedBeforeSet=(pojoMap.get("createdBefore")!=null);
```

**Method 2**

you can check the null values using reflection so here what you do

```
Map<String,boolean> pojoMap= new HashMap<>();
for(Field field : pojo.getClass().getFields()){
   field.setAccessible(true);
   pojoMap.put(field.getName(),f.get(pojo)!=null); 
}  //now pojoMap has all the names of your fields inside pojo and a boolean value
   // to check if they are null or not
```